# Laravel DB Select Query

Tags: laravel-5

I'm learning Laravel 5. Need help with query and print in blade.
I have one table with users info and one table with Steam info where I have user_id row.
How can I build this query:

```
SELECT username FROM steam WHERE id = user_id;
```

user_id is logged user in session

users table

```
id | email | username | password |
```

steam table

```
id | user_id | username | steam_id | avatar
```

Steam.php

```
<?php

namespace SGN\Models;

use SGN\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Invisnik\LaravelSteamAuth\SteamAuth;

class Steam extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'steam';

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'username',
        'avatar',
        'steamid',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

SteamController.php

```
<?php

namespace SGN\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use SGN\Models\Steam;
use Invisnik\LaravelSteamAuth\SteamAuth;

class SteamController extends Controller
{
    private $steam;

    public function __construct(SteamAuth $steam)
    {
        $this->steam = $steam;
    }

    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->steam->validate()) {
            $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $info = $this->steam->getUserInfo();
            if (!is_null($info)) {
                $user = Steam::where('steamid', $info->getSteamID64())->first();
                if (is_null($user)) {
                    $user = Steam::create([
                        'user_id' => $user_id,
                        'username' => $info->getNick(),
                        'avatar'   => $info->getProfilePictureFull(),
                        'steamid'  => $info->getSteamID64()
                    ]);
                }
                //Auth::login($user, true);
                return redirect('/'); // redirect to site
            }
        }
        return $this->steam->redirect(); // redirect to Steam login page
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return Steam::create([
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'steamid' => $data['steamid'],
            'avatar' => $data['avatar'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

edit.blade.php

```
@section('content')
    <h3>Update your profile</h3>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
              Here print steam username from DB
        </div>
    </div>
@stop
```

Comment: How do you like to communicate with your DB, are you using any models? Basic examples are given in the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database),  which is very well written.

Comment: Sorry I am new here, not sure is your question
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

Comment: Yes, but you can also use `Query Builder` from your controller for simple tasks to fetch data from your database directly using sql queries.

Comment: How from Query Builder I can print on blade?

Comment: `\DB::table('users')->where('id', 1)->first()`

Comment: 1) [Define a Model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#defining-models) for users.  2) [Define a Model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#defining-models) for steam info.  3) Define a [One To One relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) for users to steam info.  4) Pass user model to view.  5) In view do something like `{{ $user->steam->username }}`

Comment: I'm try with this
$users = DB::table('steam')->select('username')->where('user_id', 1)->get();
echo $users;
in edit.blade.php with open php tags and get this error
Array to string conversion (View: /var/www/html/test/resources/views/profile/edit.blade.php)

Comment: @MarkoStevanović you are using view template incorrectly. The fact that you try to define `$users` in the template tells me you do not understand. Templates use a specific syntax that is later turned into PHP. Please consider getting a basic hello world template working then trying again.

Comment: I'm edited post, maybe now clear for understanding